# Can't find openni2 library after successful compilation

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, openni

I'm trying to view openni color and depth frames using opencv, and I've been able to compile the code with:

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv --cflags` -I /home/myaccount/Downloads/OpenNI/Include/ testing.cpp -o newtest -L /home/myaccount/Downloads/OpenNI/Redist/ -lOpenNI2 `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

But when I run ./newtest, I get the following error:

```
./newtest: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenNI2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no clue what's going on and I'd appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Run `ldd newtest` to see where it expects to find libOpenNI2.so.  You may need to have the library in the working directory.

Comment: @piedar - It only shows libOpenNI2.so => not found for openni and most of the other libraries are in /lib and /usr/lib. Do you want to see the full output?

Comment: What happens if you move newtest to `/home/myaccount/Downloads/OpenNI/`?

Comment: @piedar - I get the same error when I move the file to the OpenNI directory.

Comment: Sorry, try `/home/myaccount/Downloads/OpenNI/Redist/`.  If that doesn't work, you may have to do some research on [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).  Unfortunately, I don't understand it quite well enough to explain.

Comment: It still isn't working. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and this resolved it as mentioned below. You didn't say which distro but if on Ubuntu you will need to add your "Redist" location of the shared library to a linker conf. So create a new file:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openni2.conf

/<your-custom-shared-lib-location>/Redist/
```

Note you only need to add the path and **not** the PATH variable in the file. Then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

The -L in the makefile refers to linking your shared libs at compile time. For runtime linking you need the above. As far as I understand this is only needed if your libs are not in the default location /usr/local/lib. This will tell the linker to include these paths for your shared libs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar problem, and I copied this file to my program's link directory that I have set before. like `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib` Then it works.

First try to locate where `libOpenNI2.so` is.  `locate libOpenNI2.so`
then or copy this file to my programs link directory. And I think 
copy this file to the system's link directory, like usr/lib, it also works.